# Ruby username and password database

Tags: arrays, ruby

Ok so i'm working on a ruby project where I want to create a database that holds username and password information that can be accessed through an array. Here's my code.

```
$ncounter = 1
$databaseArray = [["",""],["",""]]

class User
    attr_accessor :username
    attr_accessor :password

    def initialize
        puts "Welcome to the site!"
    end
end

def createUser(username, password)
    counter = $ncounter
    counter = User.new
    counter.username = username
    $databaseArray[ncounter - 1][0] = username

    counter.password = password
    $databaseArray[ncounter - 1][1] = password
    ncounter = ncounter + 1
end

createUser("Charlie", "1234")
```

Whenever I run it i get this in my console

```
Welcome to the site!
user.rb:17:in `createUser': undefined local variable or method `ncounter' for     
main:Object (NameError)
from user.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ncounter` be `$ncounter`  or should it be `counter`?  Looks like error is pretty clear

Comment: you set `counter` to the global object of `$ncounter` and then immediately overwrite it with `User.new`? Then you reference a non existent local variable `ncounter` multiple times (Error is here). Since all the "Users" will be stored in this Array `$ncounter` seems redundant to just counting the records. Finally an Array is not a database and it will be reloaded every time the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: you are referring it as `ncounter` instead of `$ncounter` in some points of `createUser` method.

**Long answer**: You should take a look in some existing gems for authentication. If this is a Rails app, I recommend you to check [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem.

Answer (score -1):

Check your code below, should be counter not ncounter:

```
def createUser(username, password)
    counter = $ncounter
    counter = User.new
    counter.username = username
    $databaseArray[counter - 1][0] = username

    counter.password = password
    $databaseArray[counter - 1][1] = password
    ncounter = ncounter + 1
end
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. User does not have a `-` method and you are still referencing `ncounter` which is not a declared local variable and I think overall you misunderstood. I am not a believer in down voting answers so I thought I'd just post a comment in hopes you will resolve this or remove the answer.